# "2 файла" + число глагола "быть" в прошедшем времени

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какое из этих двух предложений дает более грамотное и благозвучное согласование числительного с глаголом?

"2 файла было загружено." или "2 файла были загружены."

Добавлено: смысловое ударение на глагол, а не на количество.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме стилистических отличий есть и смысловые. В конструкциях, когда подлежащее выражено количественно-именным сочетанием, сказуемое может быть как в форме единственного числа (*2 файла было загружено*), так и в форме множественного числа (*2 файла были загружены*). Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совокупность предметов (в данном случае - *2 файла* как единое целое, единый объем информации), форма множественного числа – на отдельные предметы (*2 файла* как самостоятельные единицы информации). Выбор формы сказуемого зависит от того, какой смысл вы хотите придать предложению.

Comment: Спасибо, смысловое ударение идет на сказуемое. Хочу в первую очередь подчеркнуть сам факт окончания загрузки файлов, а во вторую очередь уточнить количество загруженного. Вариант "было загружено", очевидно, в этом случае лучше.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, эти предложения отличаются только по стилистическому предназначению. "2 файла было загружено" свойственно скорее более "суровому" официально-деловому или научному (например, если это научная работа - дипломная и т. д.), а 2-й вариант - "2 файла были загружены" - звучит нейтрально и будет приемлем для любого стиля.